# How to derive derivative of the logarithm of a summation?

Tags: derivatives, summation, logarithms

I'm currently reading the book [*Deep Learning (Goodfellow et al., 2015)*](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) and had a question regarding the calculation of a gradient when explaining [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) for a certain example. For anyone who's curious, this is from section *6.5.9: Differentiation outside the Deep Learning Community*.

> Suppose we have variables $p_1, p_2, ... , p_n$ representing probabilities and variables $z_1, z_2, ... , z_n$ representing unnormalized log probabilities. Suppose we define
>
> $$q_i = \frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_i e^{z_i}}$$
>
> where we build the softmax function out of exponentiation, summation and division operations, and construct a cross-entropy loss $J = -\sum_i p_i \log{q_i}$. A human mathematician can observe that the derivateive of $J$ with respect to $z_i$ takes a very simple form: $q_i - p_i$.

I don't know how this result was derived, and was hoping that someone could give me some tips or advice. What I have so far is

$$\log{q_i} = \log{e^{z_i}} - \log({\sum_i e^{z_i}})$$

$$
\begin{align}
p_i\log{q_i} & = p_i \log{e^{z_i}} - p_i \log({\sum_i e^{z_i}}) \\
& = p_iz_i - p_i\log(\sum_i e^{z_i})
\end{align}$$

If we take the derivative of $J = p_i\log{q_i}$ then I can understand that $d/dz_i (p_i z_i) = p_i$, but how do we differentiate the second term that contains the logarithm of the summation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your derivation of $p_i\log q_i$ is fine. Based upon it we obtain for $J$:

\begin{align*}
J&=-\sum_{j=1}^np_jz_j+\sum_{j=1}^np_j\log\left(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{z_k}\right)\\
&=-\sum_{j=1}^np_jz_j+\log\left(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{z_k}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

In the last line we use the sum of the probabilities $p_j,1\leq j\leq n$ is equal to $1$.

> From (1) we obtain the derivation of $J$ with respect to $z_i$ as:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{d}{dz_i}J}
> &=\frac{d}{dz_i}\left(-\sum_{j=1}^np_jz_j\right)+\frac{d}{dz_i}\left(\log\left(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{z_k}\right)\right)\\
> &=-p_i+\frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_{k=1}^ne^{z_k}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-p_i+q_i}
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial z_i}  = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} (-\sum_j p_j\log q_j )=\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}( -p_i\log q_i) \\= \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} (-p_i \log (e^{z_i}/\sum_k e^{z_k}))\\ =\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} (-p_iz_i\log e + p_i\log(\sum_k e^{z_k})) \\= \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} (-p_iz_i) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}p_i\log(\sum_k e^{z_k}) \\= -p_i + p_ie^{z_i}/\sum_k e^{z_k} \\= -p_i+p_iq_i.$$

Comment: But didn't the op claim the partial derivative to be $q_i - p_i$?

Comment: Needs checking by a human mathematician.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. In the first line why (or how) did you get rid of the symbol for summation? Is this a rule in calculus?

Comment: @Seankala: Note $p_1$ is a function of $z_1,$ but $p_2$ is not related to $z_1.$ $p_i$ for $i \neq 1 $ are all constant with respect to $z_1.$ The same argument works for the $q_i.$ The derivative is linear, and the derivative of a constant is $0.$

Comment: @Wuestenfux I think there is a mistake in the third to last line - note $z_i = \log p_i \implies p_i = e^{z_i},$ so we can't treat $p_i$ as a constant there. Likewise for $q_i.$